# Add empty paragraph mark to Office exclusion dictionary

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check

I'm trying to add an empty paragraph marker to Word's exclusion dictionary to provide the red squiggly line during spell check.  I've successfully added other words to the dictionary, so I know its the correct one and otherwise working.

I've tried adding the empty paragraph by typing only an <kbd>enter</kbd> key on one line.  I've also tried adding the Special Code `^p` found in the Find/Replace dialog.  Neither option works.

What does work is a `Find` on `^p^p`-this will find any empty paragraph in the document.  However I'd like it to be automatically flagged like a spelling or grammar error.

Comment: Not possible - the dictionary only handles *words*.

Comment: I suspected that, but wanted to confirm it.  Do you know of a primary source for the info? It seems pretty intuitive (dictionary = word), but I'm always curious about possible workarounds the documentation may include or hint at.  My plan B is deciding between VBA and just basic find/replace.